# Loop through a mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm trying to make an anonymous comment system, following is the code to print the existing comments. It is requires that I loop through the comm_id field in the database to get all the comments. How can I achieve this?

```
<ol id="update" class="timeline">
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from comments where com_id='' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql) )
{
$comment=$row['comment'];
?>
<li class="box">
<?php echo $comment; ?>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What's your table structure? what do you mean by loop through the `com_id` fields?

Comment: Remove `where com_id=''`

Comment: com_id is the integer value i've assigned to each comment.

Comment: Do you just want to show each comments?? Then it is in fact removing `where com_id=''` from your database query.

Comment: Thanks @ArushiChhabra the answer of this question also solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove `where com_id=''`.  This will select *all* of the comments unconditionally.

---

Please avoid using `ext/mysql` and use `PDO`/`mysqli` if you can.  No need to use `SELECT *`.  You can just select the `comment` column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
It will show all comments from your database table

```
<ol id="update" class="timeline">
  <?php
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from comments");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql) )
    {
    $comment=$row['comment'];
    ?>
    <li class="box">
    <?php echo $comment; ?>
    </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this `where com_id=''` then it will consider all the comment and then display in loop:

```
<ol id="update" class="timeline">
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from comments  ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql) )
{
$comment=$row['comment'];
?>
<li class="box">
<?php echo $comment; ?>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```